# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance method '[]' when getting data from openweathermap

Tags: flutter, dart, openweathermap

I am building a weather app using OpenWeatherMap API.

Whenever I am passing latitude and longitude then I am getting the data correctly:

```
Future<dynamic> getWeatherData(double latitude, double longitude) async{
    Network network = Network();
    var weatherData = await network.getJson("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$latitude&lon=$longitude&appid=$APP_ID&units=metric");
    return weatherData;
  }
```

I am using `weatherData` like this:

```
void updateWeather(dynamic weatherData){
    Weather weather = Weather();
    setState(() {
      if (weatherData == null){
        temperature = 0;
        temperatureIcon = "";
        temperatureText = "Can't find weather, make sure GPS is on";
        return;
      }
      temperature = weatherData["main"]["temp"];
      int condition = weatherData["weather"][0]["id"];
      temperatureIcon = weather.getWeatherIcon(condition);
      temperatureText = weather.getMessage(temperature);
    });
```

I am using `temperatureIcon` and `temperatureText` in `Text()` widgets below.

Now I was adding the feature to get weather by searching city name:

```
var cityName = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context){
                          return Search();
                        }
                      ));
                      if (cityName != null && cityName.toString().isNotEmpty){
                        Weather weather = Weather();
                        var weatherData = weather.getWeatherDataCity(cityName);
                        updateWeather(weatherData);
                      }
```

getWeatherDataCity():

```
Future<dynamic> getWeatherDataCity(String cityName) async{
    Network network = Network();
    var weatherData = await network.getJson("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$cityName&appid=$APP_ID&units=metric");
    return weatherData;
  }
```

but when I run this code I get this exception:

```
E/flutter ( 3250): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance method '[]'.
E/flutter ( 3250): Receiver: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
E/flutter ( 3250): Tried calling: []("main")
E/flutter ( 3250): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
E/flutter ( 3250): #1      WeatherScreenState.updateWeather.<anonymous closure> (package:clima/screens/weather_screen.dart:39:32)
E/flutter ( 3250): #2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1088:30)
E/flutter ( 3250): #3      WeatherScreenState.updateWeather (package:clima/screens/weather_screen.dart:32:5)
E/flutter ( 3250): #4      WeatherScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:clima/screens/weather_screen.dart:86:25)
E/flutter ( 3250): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Why am I getting this exception?

The JSON data received is the same when I put city name or latitude and longitude.

Network.getJson():

```
class Network{

  Future<dynamic> getJson(String url) async{
    Response response = await get(Uri.parse(url));
    print(response.body);
    return response.statusCode >= 200 ? jsonDecode(response.body) : null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have two methods in network, one is `getWeatherData` and `getJson`

Answer (score 2):

Try awaiting for this function:

```
var weatherData = await weather.getWeatherDataCity(cityName);
```

Life would also be a lot easier and code would make more sense if you eliminated all the `dynamic` and `var` and used objects.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, but with Sir @Huthaifa Muayyad's answer solved my issue.
You have to use await as follows:

var weatherData = await weather.getWeatherDataCity(cityName);